# FileHelpers - string length issue?

Tags: etl, rhino, filehelpers, rhino-etl

I'm moving some data about using rhino.etl

One of the tables I'm moving has a column which stores a fairly large chunk of text for each row - though it's not that huge and there are only about 2000 rows.

When running the job I get:

A first chance exception of type 'FileHelpers.FileHelpersException' occurred in FileHelpers.dll

Now, removing the large text column fixes the issue - this is the only output I get though.

Is there a restriction somewhere that dictates a limit on data size or something?

Debug output: [monobin](http://monobin.com/__mb68d839)

Comment: You can try updating the Dll to the last version: http://teamcity.codebetter.com/repository/download/bt65/19195:id/FileHelpers_2.9.9_DebugBuild.zip  Inside the zip folder Lib\2.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer of FileHelpers, can you post here the stack trace and the full message of the exception ?

For filehelpers there is no limit to the string length, but maybe the column stores the info as binary data and Rhino.Etl send it that way

Best Regards

Comment: Hi Marcos, Please see the below stack trace for more details.